# How to Intercept @transactional arguments if @transactional applied at class level

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to capture the argument of @transactional if it is applied at class level.

for e.g. if `@transactional` applied at method level like :-

```
class A {

    @transactional(readOnly= true)
    public void someMethod(){
      // some code...
     }
}
```

then I am able to Intercept and capture the formal argument i.e. readOnly with this code like :-

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(0)
public class ReadOnlyRouteInterceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadOnlyRouteInterceptor.class);

    @Around("@annotation(transactional)")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Transactional transactional) {
            if (transactional.readOnly())
             //do something
    }
```

However the above code will not work if `@transactional` applied at class level as :-

```
@transactional(readOnly= true)
class A {

    public void someMethod(){
      // some code...
     }
}
```

Now in order to Intercept the `@transactional` annotation which is applied at class level  I have following code :-

```
@Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional *)")
public void beanAnnotatedWithTransactional() {}

@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
public void publicMethod() {}

@Pointcut("publicMethod() && beanAnnotatedWithTransactional()")
public void publicMethodInsideAClassMarkedWithATransactional() {}
```

My actual problem here is I am unable to check the value of readOnly flag if `@transactional` is applied at class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For type level annotation :

```
@Around("@within(transactional)")
public Object myMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Transactional transactional) throws Throwable {
    boolean readOnly = transactional.readOnly();
    ...
    return pjp.proceed();
}
```

For method level annotation:

```
  @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public Object myMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();

        Transactional annotation = method.getAnnotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional.class);
        boolean value = annotation. readOnly();
        ...
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
```

Another (cleaner) option for method level :

```
@Around("@annotation(transactional)")
 public Object myMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Transactional transactional) throws Throwable {
```

}

or

With more control over tager :

```
    @Around("execution(@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional public * *(..)) && @annotation("transactional")
     public Object myMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Transactional transactional) throws Throwable {

}
```

Comment: Couple of observations .1. Second set of code will not work for Type level annotation as mentioned. 2. Consider we have DeptService Interface and DeptServiceImpl class implementing the only method updateDept() in it .The method.getAnnotation() to work without NPE , the interface method  should be annotated with Transactional .Only annotating the implementing class method will result in NPE . The annotation details will be always from the interface method and not from the implementing class method , so any override to the behaviour ( eg: readonly ) will not be captured correctly.

Comment: Just FYI fg78nc your code was Intercepting the type level as well as a method-level annotation. The only challenge I faced was method.getAnnotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional.class) was resulting null even if @transactional(readonly=true) annotation applied at method level(I do not know the reason)

whereas declaringClass.getAnnotation(Transactional.class) was returning the correct result if the annotation applied to class level.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [TransactionSynchronizationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html) to get reference to the transaction details.

Following code provides the readonly details of the current active transaction.

```
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

@Component
@Aspect
public class TestTransactionalAspect {


    @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public void beanAnnotatedWithTransactional() {}
    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {}


    @Around("publicMethod() && beanAnnotatedWithTransactional()")
    public void publicMethodInsideAClassMarkedWithATransactional(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Intercepted "+pjp.toShortString());
            if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
                System.out.println("Is transaction readonly : "+TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
            }
            pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Update:**

Assuming this is not a Spring Boot project , [@EnableTransactionManagement](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) is mandatory for your spring application to work with transactions. Data will get persisted to database without transactions as well.

> @EnableTransactionManagement annotation has to be used on
>   @Configuration classes.

Following is a sample code to enable transaction management in spring

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

         @Bean
         public FooRepository fooRepository() {
             // configure and return a class having @Transactional methods
             return new JdbcFooRepository(dataSource());
         }

         @Bean
         public DataSource dataSource() {
             // configure and return the necessary JDBC DataSource
         }

         @Bean
         public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
             return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
         }
     }
```

Comment: I tried with this approach but this is not working if @Transactional applied at class level.
Both static method i.e. isActualTransactionActive & isCurrentTransactionReadOnlyis returning false.

Comment: Please confirm if a configuration class is annotated with @EnableTransactionManagement  to enable transactions ? isActualTransactionActive false means no transaction is active . The code shared is tested and working as expected

Comment: configuration class is not annotated with @EnableTransactionManagement. It is only annotated with @transactional(readOnly=true).
I am getting isActualTransactionActive false in my aspect advice but able to get the data from the DB.

Should I change my service class A like this :-

Comment: @EnableTransaction
@transactional(readOnly=true)
class daoImpl {
//methods
}

Comment: I am using @Repository annotation on my DaoImpl class hence JPA configuration is not required in my case.
I tried your approach but it does not work for method level as well.

Comment: Repository is just a stereotype annotation. Without EnableTransactionManagement annotation no transactions will happen in your application. You may need to confirm if any transactions are actually happening. The code shared is verified and it works

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers above I tried with the following code it is very simple.

```
 /**
     * This Aspect advice will be called only if transactional applied at method level
     */
    @Around("@annotation(transactional)")
    public Object proceedWithMethodLevelAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint,
                                                   Transactional transactional)  {
                                      if( transactional.readOnly() ) {
                //do something
                  }

    /**
     * This Aspect advice will be called only if transactional annotation applied at class level
     */
    @Around("@within(transactional)")
    public Object proceedWithClassLevelAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint,
                                                  Transactional transactional) 
            if( transactional.readOnly() ) {
            //do something
    }
}
```