# Aspect does not triggered

Tags: spring, readonly, aspect

I am trying to implement read-only data source in my application.

According to the following repo implementation, this aspect method should be called when a transaction happens but it never triggers this method(This line never printed to the console - System.out.println("Aspect executed");

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(0)
public class TransactionReadonlyAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(transactional)")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional transactional) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Aspect executed");
        try {
            if (transactional.readOnly()) {
                DatabaseContextHolder.set(DatabaseEnvironment.READONLY);
            }
            return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            DatabaseContextHolder.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

And also in the following class it initializes the default datasource no matter what,

How can I make this works or what are the other confihgurations I need to add ?

Thanks.

```
  package com.programmingsharing.demoreadwriterouting.conf;
    
    import com.programmingsharing.demoreadwriterouting.context.DatabaseEnvironment;
    import com.programmingsharing.demoreadwriterouting.datasource.MasterSlaveRoutingDataSource;
    import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    @Configuration
    public class DataSourceConfiguration {
    
        @Value("${jdbc.master.url}")
        private String mstUrl;
    
        @Value("${jdbc.master.username}")
        private String mstUsername;
    
        @Value("${jdbc.master.password}")
        private String mstPassword;
    
        @Value("${jdbc.slave.url}")
        private String slaveUrl;
    
        @Value("${jdbc.slave.username}")
        private String slaveUsername;
    
        @Value("${jdbc.slave.password}")
        private String slavePassword;
    
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource(){
            MasterSlaveRoutingDataSource masterSlaveRoutingDataSource = new MasterSlaveRoutingDataSource();
            Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
            targetDataSources.put(DatabaseEnvironment.UPDATABLE, masterDataSource());
            targetDataSources.put(DatabaseEnvironment.READONLY, slaveDataSource());
            masterSlaveRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    
            // Set as all transaction point to master
            masterSlaveRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource());
            return masterSlaveRoutingDataSource;
        }
    
        public DataSource slaveDataSource() {
    
            HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
            hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(slaveUrl);
            hikariDataSource.setUsername(slaveUsername);
            hikariDataSource.setPassword(slavePassword);
            return hikariDataSource;
        }
    
        public DataSource masterDataSource() {
            HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
            hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(mstUrl);
            hikariDataSource.setUsername(mstUsername);
            hikariDataSource.setPassword(mstPassword);
            return hikariDataSource;
        }
    }
```

https://programmingsharing.com/routing-read-write-datasource-in-spring-99bcc4468f94

Also

context is always printed null
CONTEXT.get() : null

```
public class DatabaseContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<DatabaseEnvironment> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void set(DatabaseEnvironment databaseEnvironment) {
        CONTEXT.set(databaseEnvironment);
    }

    public static DatabaseEnvironment getEnvironment() {
        System.out.println("CONTEXT.get() : " + CONTEXT.get());
        return CONTEXT.get();
    }

    public static void reset() {
        CONTEXT.set(DatabaseEnvironment.UPDATABLE);
    }

}
```

Also this is always null, none of the environment variables doe not set
DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment() : null

```
public class MasterSlaveRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        System.out.println("DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment() : " + DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment());
        return DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have somewhere a method annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` ?

Comment: Yes, I am calling my service with annotated   @Transactional(readOnly = true) and not annotated one, no one triggers and always go the write datasource

Comment: THe annotation should include the full qualified name of the annotation, `transactional` isn't the name of an annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you give an example please

Comment: As @M.Deinum pointed out, the pointcut is not defined correctly. Try to define it in the following way: `@annotation(javax.transaction.Transactional)`

Comment: I didn't notice the parameter binding, my bad. So if you are actually using that annotation it, in theory, should work. However it isn't clear if you are using Spring Boot or not, if you don't you need an `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in your configuration else the aspect won't do a thing.

Comment: I have tried the following one and gave an error as. "Unbound pointcut parameter 'transactional'     "@Around("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")

Comment: I have added @EnableAspectJAutoProxy, no change

Comment: With what you have given so far it should work, if it doesn't there is something in your setup that breaks things. However as you haven't included much more then your aspect and your datasource setup this is thus impossible to know.

Comment: remove `@Component`, `@Aspect` should be enough.  I assume you've got `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in a config somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

That obviously not the answer to your Q, however I would discourage you from using that datasource routing "solution" you are referring to.

The problem is from `spring-tx` perspective transaction is `read-only` if and only if the outermost transaction definition is readonly, please check some examples of execution stacks below:

```
@Transactional(readonly=true)

  ...

  @Transactional(readonly=false)
  // current tx is read-only regardless readonly=false definition
```

```
@Transactional(readonly=false)

  ...

  @Transactional(readonly=true)
  // current tx is not read-only regardless readonly=true definition
```

"AspectJ" solution does not take into account that `spring-tx` convention and thus it is basically wrong.

Technically, we may determine whether transaction is read-only or not via calling `TransactionSynchronizationManager#isCurrentTransactionReadOnly` method, unfortunately that won't help us much because `spring-tx` may acquire resources (jdbc connection) before marking transaction as read-only, this problem was mentioned by Vlad Mihalcea in [Read-write and read-only transaction routing with Spring](https://vladmihalcea.com/read-write-read-only-transaction-routing-spring/):

> Not only that the hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit allows you to make better use of database connections, but **it’s the only way we can make this example work since, without this configuration, the connection is acquired prior to calling the determineCurrentLookupKey method TransactionRoutingDataSource**.

There are two options:

1. if you are using `Hibernate` - just follow Vlad's recommendations
2. if you are not using `Hibernate` you need to take into account that you need to control outermost transaction definitions only - just place there your own annotations/aspects and do not depend on `spring-tx` stuff.

Comment: well thanks for the answer, for Vlad post I came across first this implementation but when tried to use "TransactionRoutingConfiguration" class it requires the implementation of all dependent classes and goes all the way to override Database.java class, so it is needed to write to the implement all library. Do you have any simple approach for implementing TransactionRoutingConfiguration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553908/how-to-intercept-transactional-arguments-if-transactional-applied-at-class-lev I think there is a solution for this one. Because Vlad approach is way compilcated. What do you think ?